# how to store bootstrap color picker values to mysql database

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap

need use bootstrap color picker plugin to store color in to the table. later this color values may use to indicate some color in the application. hope to use this plugins http://www.expertphp.in/article/simple-jquery-bootstrap-color-picker-plugin-example

My problem is this in My data table may I use both columns names like "color_name" and "color_value" or is it enough only "color_value" and I need data types also.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `colors` (

  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `color_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  `color` BINARY(3) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

);
```

Comment: i will suggest you  varchar

Comment: the structure of your tables are up to you; but having color_name will be helpful

Comment: is bootstrap color picker provide both color name and color value to store table?